# Post-build Web.config transforms

Tags: msbuild, web.config-transform

I have an unfortunate situation where I need to deploy one Visual Studio project eight times via `webdeploy` with differently transformed `web.config` files for each deployment.

Is it possible to transform the `web.config` configuration with MSBuild after a single build instead of compiling multiple times just to transform the configuration file?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can roll your own web config transformations using the xdt tool, rebuilding to do web transforms is just wrong: 
http://ctt.codeplex.com/